# Assets\Scripts\Flight Simulator\Flight Sim.cs(69,5): error CS0825: The contextual keyword "var' may only appear within a local variable declaration

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This code isn't origianlly mine, but I'm having issues with it regardless I have check the code for any missing elements and also check out what I could do to fix it but couldn't find the answer.

```
void Calculatestate(float dt, bool firstThisFrame)
{
    var invRotation = Quaternion.Inverse(Rigidbody.rotation);
    Velocity = Rigidbody.velocity;
    LocalVelocity = invRotation * Velocity; //Transform world velocity into local space
    LocalAngularVelocity = invRotation * Rigibody.angularVelocity; //Transform into local space

    CalculateAngleOfAttack();
}

void CalculateAngleOfAttack()
{
    AngleOfAttack = Mathf.Atan2(-LocalVelocity.y, LocalVelocity.z);
    AngleOfAttackYaw = Mathf.Atan2(LocalVelocity.x, LocalVelocity.z);
}

void CalculateGForce(float dt)
{
    var invRotation = Quaternion.Inverse(Rigidbody.rotation);
    var acceleration = (Velocity - lastVelocity) / dt;
    localGForce = invRotation * acceleration;
    lastVelocity = Velocity;
}

void UpdateThrust()
{
    Rigidbody.AddRelativeForce(Throttle * maxThrust * Vector3.forward);
}

void UpdateDrag()
{
    var lv = LocalVelocity;
    var lv2 = lv.sqrMagnitude; //Velocity squared

    //Calculate coefficient of drag depending on direction on velocity
    var coefficient = Utilities.Scale6 (
        lv.normalized,
        dragRight, dragLeft,
        dragTop, dragBottom,
        dragFoward, dragBack
    );

    var drag = coefficient.magntude * lv2 * -lv.normalized; //drag is oppositte direction of velocity

    Rigidbody.AddRelativeForce(drag);
}

float airbrakeDrag = AirbrakeDeployed ? this.airbrakeDrag : 0;
float flapsDrag = flapsDeployed ? this.flapsDrag : 0;

var coefficient = Utilities.Scale6(
    lv.normalized,
    dragRight.Evaluate(Mathf.Abs(lv.x)), dragLeft.Evaluate(Mathf.Abs(lv.x)),
    dragTop.Evaluate(Mathf.Abs(lv.y)), dragBottom.Evaluate(Mathf.Abs(lv.y)),
    dragForward.Evaluate(Mathf.Abs(lv.z)) + airbrakeDrag + flapsDrag, //Include Extra drag for forward coefficient
    dragBack.Evaluate(Mathf.Abs(lv.z))
);

Vector3 CalculateLift(float angleOfAttack, Vector3 rightAxis, float liftPower, AnimationCurve aoaCurve, AnimationCurve inducedDragCurve)
{
    var liftVelocity = Vector3. ProjectOnPlane(LocalVelocity, rightAxis); // Project Velocity onto YZ plane
    var v2 = liftVelocity.sqrMagnitude; //Square of Velocity

    //lift = velocity^2 * liftPower
    //cpefficient varies with AOA
    var liftCoefficient = aoaCurve.Evaluate(angleOfAttack * Mathf.Rad2Deg);
    var liftForce = v2 * liftCoefficient * liftPower;

    //Lift is perpendicular to velocity
    var liftDirection = Vector3.Cross(liftVelocity.normalized, rightAxis);
    var lift = liftDirection * liftForce;

    //Induced drag varies with square of lift coeffiecient
    var dragForce = liftCoefficient * liftCoefficient;
    var dragDirection = -liftVelocity.normalized;
    var inducedDrag = dragDirection * v2 * dragForce * this.inducedDrag * inducedDragCurve.Evaluate(mathf.Max(0, localVelocity.z));

    return lift + inducedDrag;
}

void UpdateLift()
{
    float flapsliftPower = FlapsDeployed ? this.flapsLiftPower : 0;
    float flapsAOABias = FlapsDeployed ? this.flapsAOABias : 0; 

    var liftForce = CalculateLift(
        angleOfAttack + (flapsAOABias * Mathf.Deg2Rad), Vector3.right,
        liftPower + flapsliftPower,
        liftAOACurve,
        inducedDragCurve
    );

    var yawForce = CalculateLift(AngleOfAttackYaw, Vector3.up, rudderPower, rudderAOACurve, rudderInducedDragCurve);

    Rigidbody.AddRelativeForce(liftForce);
    Rigidbody.AddRelativeForce(yawForce);
}

float CalculateSteering(float dt, float angularVelocity, float targetVelocity, float acceleration)
{
    var error = targetVelocity - angularVelocity;
    var accel = acceleration * dt; 
    return Mathf.Clamp(error, -accel, accel);
}

void UpdateSteering (float dt)
{
    var speed = Mathf.Max(0, LocalVelocity.z);
    var steeringPower = steeringPowerCurve.Evaluate(speed);

    var targetAV = Vector3.Scale(controlInput, turnSpeed * steeringPower);
    var av = LocalAngularVelocity * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    
    var correction = new Vector3(
        CalculateSteering(dt, av.x, targetAV.x, turnAcceleration.x * steeringPower),
        CalculateSteering(dt, av.y, targetAV.y, turnAcceleration.y * steeringPower),
        CalculateSteering(dt, av.z, targetAV.z, turnAcceleration.z * steeringPower)
    );

    Rigidbody.AddRelativeTorque(correction * Mathf.Deg2Rad, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    //ignore rigidbody mass
}
Vector3 CalculateGForce(Vector3 angularVelocity, Vector3 velocity)
{
    //estimate G Force from angular velocity and velocity
    //Velocity = AngularVelocity * Radius
    //G = Velocity^2 / R
    //G = (Velocity * AngularVelocity * Radius) / Radius
    //G = Velocity * AngularVelocity
    //G =  V cross A
    return Vector3.Cross(angularVelocity, velocity);
}
Vector3 CalculateGForceLimit(Vector3 input)
{
    return Utilities.Scale6(input,
    gLimit, gLimitPitch, //Pitch down, Pitch up
    gLimit, gLimit, //yaw
    gLimit, gLimit //roll
    ) * 9.81f;
}
float CalculateGLimiter(Vector3 controlInput, Vector3 maxAngularVelocity)
{
    //If the player gives input with magnitude lessthan 1, scale up their input so that magnitude == 1
    var maxInput = controlInput.normalized;

    var limit = CalculateGForceLimit(maxInput);
    var maxGforce = CalculateGForce(Vector3,Scale(maxInput, maxAngularVelocity), LocalVelocity);

    if (maxGforce.magnitude > limit.magnitude)
    {
        //Example
        //maxGForce = 16G, limit = 8G
        //so this is 8 / 16 or 0.5
        return limit.magnitude / maxGforce.magnitude;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

}

Here's the link to the code I'm using: https://vazgriz.com/346/flight-simulator-in-unity3d-part-1/

I tried to find if it had any missing element or any details, but the couldn't. Alright tried adding strings into it, but that only got me a whole set of codes. Like for example, Type 'flight sim' already defines a memeber called 'Caculatestate' with same parameter types, or The namespace '<global namespace' already contain a definition for 'FlightSim'

Comment: As explained in the web page, that code block is the **final** version of the code of the function `UpdateDrag`.

Answer (score -2):

The error is saying exactly what the problem is

[image]

a VAR keyword is being used outside a local context, and as VAR detect the type implicit on the fly it cannot be used outside inner contexts, just change it to whatever type the Utilities.Scale6 is and you will be good to go

Comment: No, they will not be good to go. Just looking at the arguments passed to `Utilities.Scale6` should tell you that they will not be good to go when applying your advice...

Comment: good to go to next problem

Comment: That's a good one, i'll give you that :-)
Still, your repartee unfortunately doesn't make your answer any better.. :-(